# How to show Multiple color text in same Text view with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display text in multiple colors/style within same Text() component. How can i achieve this using Jetpack Compose?

Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using an AnnotatedString in Compose. A custom composable can be created which takes the two colors and strings as parameter like below.

```
 @Composable
 fun MultiStyleText(text1: String, color1: Color, text2: String, color2: Color) {
        Text(buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = color1)) {
                append(text1)
            }
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = color2)) {
                append(text2)
            }
        })
    }
```

This composable can then be used in your code as below.

```
  MultiColorText("OS Version: ", Color.DarkGray, "Android 12", Color.Blue)
```

You may add more customization and different styles to different parts of the string.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#multiple-styles

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **List** of pairs to define the text-color pairs. This way, you can display any number of styled text segments with their respective colors.

```
@Composable
fun MultiColorText(vararg textWithColors: Pair<String, Color>) {
    Text(buildAnnotatedString {
        textWithColors.forEach { (text, color) ->
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = color)) {
                append(text)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

now pass any number of text-color pairs to create a multi-styled text view.

```
MultiColorText(
                Pair("OS Version: ", Color.DarkGray),
                Pair("Android 12", Color.Blue),
                Pair("\n\nJetpack Compose", Color.Black),
                Pair(" is awesome!", Color.Magenta)
            )
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

and you can check this snippet of code as well

```
Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            Text(text = "Version:",color = Color.Black)
            Text(text = "Android 12",color = Color.Blue)
        }
```

Comment: Not a useful answer